# Android shared java library

Tags: java, android, shared-libraries, android-library

**Context:**

I am working on an android application that uses multiple libraries.
One of those libraries can vary depending on the device (implementation can differ)
To avoid having to build multiple version of the application the idea would be to have a unique version of the app that links to the said library on the device. The library will them use flavors to have variants

In my application manifest I have added this:

```xml
<uses-library android:name="com.lib.package"/>
```

In my build.gradle I have put this:

```
dependencies {
  // ...
  compileOnly project(path: ":path_to_lib")
}
```

By having compile only the compiler knows which class is available at compile time we intend to keep the exact same interfaces across flavors

**Problem:**

When I launch the application from Android studio it will not boot since the library is not available.

So far I have not found a way to install the library onto the device so that it can be linked dynamically to the app at install.

Is what I am trying possible or am I totally of track ?

Comment: Java libraries are not designed to be installed, they are part of the app. So if you want to use application specific code you have to do that inside the library using conditional execution, but multiple versions don't work on Android, especially on the latest Android versions as Google wants to eliminate dynamic code loading for security reasons.